# XML, php foreach

Tags: php, xml, foreach, simplexml

I'm trying to output data from an XML file.

Here's an excerpt from the XML file:

```
<TAF>
<raw_text>
TAF AMD EGBB 242124Z 2421/2518 11006KT 6000 BKN020 TEMPO 2421/2424 4000 +SHRA TSRA BECMG 2421/2424 BKN009 PROB30 2500/2506 4000 BR BKN004 BECMG 2506/2508 9999 SCT020 TEMPO 2508/2518 7000 SHRA PROB30 TEMPO 2508/2518 33015G25KT 4000 +TSRA BECMG 2515/2518 35010KT
</raw_text>
<station_id>EGBB</station_id>
<issue_time>2012-08-24T21:24:00Z</issue_time>
<valid_time_from>2012-08-24T21:00:00Z</valid_time_from>
<valid_time_to>2012-08-25T18:00:00Z</valid_time_to>

<forecast>
    <fcst_time_from>2012-08-24T21:00:00Z</fcst_time_from>
    <fcst_time_to>2012-08-25T18:00:00Z</fcst_time_to>
    <wind_dir_degrees>110</wind_dir_degrees>
    <wind_speed_kt>6</wind_speed_kt>
    <visibility_statute_mi>3.73</visibility_statute_mi>
    <sky_condition sky_cover="BKN" cloud_base_ft_agl="2000"/>
</forecast>
<forecast>
    <fcst_time_from>2012-08-24T21:00:00Z</fcst_time_from>
    <fcst_time_to>2012-08-25T00:00:00Z</fcst_time_to>
    <change_indicator>TEMPO</change_indicator>
    <visibility_statute_mi>2.49</visibility_statute_mi>
    <wx_string>+SHRA TSRA</wx_string>
</forecast>
</TAF>
```

Maybe there's a few more `<forecast>`. My question is how do I fill them out into a foreach loop to output data for each `<forecast>` element under `<TAF>`?

I am currently using:

```
$xml_taf->data->TAF[0]->forecast
```

to access the data inside the XML with SimpleXML.

Comment: As in... `foreach($xml_taf->data->TAF[0]->forecast as $forecast)`?

Comment: You showed us what you're currently using, but does it work? If not, please show the whole XML structure (i.e. why you tried `$xml_tag->data->…`) as the problem isn't in the fragment that you gave above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure what you are doing but this works

```
$xml = '<TAF>
<raw_text>
TAF AMD EGBB 242124Z 2421/2518 11006KT 6000 BKN020 TEMPO 2421/2424 4000 +SHRA TSRA BECMG 2421/2424 BKN009 PROB30 2500/2506 4000 BR BKN004 BECMG 2506/2508 9999 SCT020 TEMPO 2508/2518 7000 SHRA PROB30 TEMPO 2508/2518 33015G25KT 4000 +TSRA BECMG 2515/2518 35010KT
</raw_text>
<station_id>EGBB</station_id>
<issue_time>2012-08-24T21:24:00Z</issue_time>
<valid_time_from>2012-08-24T21:00:00Z</valid_time_from>
<valid_time_to>2012-08-25T18:00:00Z</valid_time_to>

<forecast>
    <fcst_time_from>2012-08-24T21:00:00Z</fcst_time_from>
    <fcst_time_to>2012-08-25T18:00:00Z</fcst_time_to>
    <wind_dir_degrees>110</wind_dir_degrees>
    <wind_speed_kt>6</wind_speed_kt>
    <visibility_statute_mi>3.73</visibility_statute_mi>
    <sky_condition sky_cover="BKN" cloud_base_ft_agl="2000"/>
</forecast>
<forecast>
    <fcst_time_from>2012-08-24T21:00:00Z</fcst_time_from>
    <fcst_time_to>2012-08-25T00:00:00Z</fcst_time_to>
    <change_indicator>TEMPO</change_indicator>
    <visibility_statute_mi>2.49</visibility_statute_mi>
    <wx_string>+SHRA TSRA</wx_string>
</forecast>
</TAF>';

echo "<pre>";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ( $xml->forecast as $forecast ) {
    print( $forecast->fcst_time_from . ","  . $forecast->fcst_time_to . "," . $forecast->visibility_statute_mi . PHP_EOL);
}
```

Output

```
2012-08-24T21:00:00Z,2012-08-25T18:00:00Z,3.73
2012-08-24T21:00:00Z,2012-08-25T00:00:00Z,2.49
```

[See Live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/aen1Oa)